# Pass a map to External function

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have the following module

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare variable $datasets as map:map external;

...
```

I want to call this so I do an `xdmp:invoke` like this

```
...
let $update := xdmp:invoke("/app/lib/my-module.xqy", (xs:QName("datasets"), $map),   <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
              <modules>{xdmp:modules-database()}</modules>
            </options>)
...
```

`$map` is of type map:map.

Running this gives me the following error

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-ARG: xdmp:invoke("/app/lib/20140527-0916-copy-y-axis-labels-from-chart-to-dataset-...", fn:QName("", "datasets"), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><modules>0</modules></options>) -- Invalid argument
```

Why is that?

Comment: I built a minimal test case that matches your code fragments above, and it worked fine for me. Can you post the full modules?

Comment: Are you sure $map is `map:map` is a singleton and not a sequence? Or not a map that's been serialized to XML? Try executing `$map instance of map:map` to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure from the limited code samples you've posted, but I think that your `$map` variable is bound to the empty sequence (the rough analogue of `null` in XPath/XQuery).

I've created the following main module, that simply returns the external variable `$datasets`:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare variable $datasets as map:map external;
$datasets
```

Invoking it as follows works correctly:

```
let $map := map:entry("key", "value")
return
  xdmp:invoke("/test.xqy",
    (xs:QName("datasets"), $map),
      <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
        <modules>{xdmp:modules-database()}</modules>
      </options>)
```

This results in the "invalid argument" error:

```
let $map := ()
return
  xdmp:invoke("/test.xqy",
    (xs:QName("datasets"), $map),
      <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
        <modules>{xdmp:modules-database()}</modules>
      </options>)
```

XQuery flattens sequences (they don't nest like s-expressions), <del>so when `$map` is the empty sequence, the `<options/>` element becomes the value of the `$datasets` param, which is an invalid value for the external variable.</del>

**Update**: Doh! @mblakele's comments below explain the error conditions ...

TL;DR: `()` is not an instance of `map:map`.

Comment: Yes, `$map` is empty. But to quibble, that doesn't flatten the second and third arguments. Each argument is still separate. What happened was that the second argument was `fn:QName("", "datasets")` by itself. The `xdmp:invoke` sequence has to be an even-numbered sequence of QName and item, so `xdmp:invoke` threw an `XMDP-ARG` error.

Comment: One way to guard against this is to check the variable types explicitly: for example `(xs:QName("datasets"), $map treat as map:map)`. Another is to bind using strong typing: `let $map as map:map := ...`. Using either or both of those forms should make the error messages easier to understand. For example `treat as` throws `XDMP-TREAT: Invalid treat: () treat as map:map`.